# Issue with C# HTTP ReadWriteTimeout

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest

I'm playing around with the `HttpWebRequest` class and got confused about the Timeout/ReadWriteTimeout members. The issues is that the ReadWriteTimeout gets ignored sometimes and then my application hangs exactly 5 minutes on my `GetResponse()` call. Sometimes it simply throws a `WebException` and sometimes it hangs for 5 minutes, which seems to be the default value. I even check the ReadWriteTimeout value before calling `GetResponse()` and it's always the correct value, which I set to *10000*.

```
var getPage = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
getPage.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
getPage.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.19) Gecko/20110707 Firefox/3.6.19";
getPage.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
getPage.Method = "GET";
getPage.CookieContainer = foo;
getPage.Proxy = proxyHTTP;
getPage.Timeout = 10000;
getPage.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
```

// in another function where I pass the getPage to

```
Console.WriteLine("Timeout: {0} / ReadWriteTimeout{1}", page.Timeout, page.ReadWriteTimeout);

var pageResponse = (HttpWebResponse)page.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("It reaches this line after 5 minutes");
if (pageResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // read and close it afterwards
}
```

I am using a **HTTP Proxy**. The weird part is that the url loads fine in the browser. I'd be thankful for any input.

// EDIT BELOW

```
namespace Proxy
{
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        var htmlResponse = new StringBuilder();
        var RequestPage = BuildHttpRequest("https://twitter.com/signup");
        GetHttpResponse(RequestPage, htmlResponse);
    }
    public static HttpWebRequest BuildHttpRequest(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var getPage = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebProxy proxyHTTP = new WebProxy("201.38.194.50", 3128);


            getPage.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            getPage.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.19) Gecko/20110707 Firefox/3.6.19";
            getPage.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            getPage.Method = "GET";
            getPage.Proxy = proxyHTTP;
            getPage.Timeout = 10000;
            getPage.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
            return getPage;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }
    public static bool GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest page, StringBuilder html)
    {
        html.Clear();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
            var pageResponse = (HttpWebResponse)page.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("5 minutes!");
            if (pageResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                var reader = new StreamReader(pageResponse.GetResponseStream());
                html.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
                pageResponse.Close();
                reader.Close();
                return true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(pageResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
            pageResponse.Close();
            return false;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

}

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
    System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: can you paste the exact error you are getting...?

Comment: There is no error, it simply hangs for 5 minutes which is the default value for ReadWriteTimeout. Then it throws the WebException.

Comment: question is the time set in seconds or milliseconds for the default.. perhaps you may need to adjust the times down and see..

Comment: It's milliseconds, adjusting the time won't change anything because it simply ignores it. Other proxies timeout fine after 10 seconds, but this one doesn't.

Comment: Ok I understand now.. ok hold on

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  Here is the proxy - 201.38.194.50:3128 and the url I am trying to access is https://twitter.com/signup

Comment: You said that sometimes it simply throws a WebException and sometimes it hangs for five minutes. Is the WebException always a timeout?

Comment: @Jim Mischel I don't remember, sorry. I just re-opened it and I'll tell you in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Yeah I just checked it and got the following WebException - "The operation has timed out"

Comment: @John Saunders In five minutes I'll post the stacktrace!

Comment: Not just the stack trace. Post ex.ToString()

Comment: @John Saunders I will in few minutes. I just made a small example to test it so I can be sure that nothing else is causing it, and still the same issue. Please read the edit.

Comment: @John Saunders The new edit includes the complete exception.

Comment: Is that the entire output of `ex.ToString()`?

Comment: @John Saunders I removed the first line because it's too long. It just says on which line the exception has been caused, and when I go to the line it's the one where GetResponse is being called.

Comment: @John Saunders I assume this is just a deep issue with .NET itself? I have tried everything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (var pageResponse = request.GetResponse())
    {
       // Do stuff with `response` here 
    } 
// drop the as HttpWebRequest; 

// The response however is, these will eventually be reclaimed by the GC 
// but you'll run into problems similar to deadlocks if you don't dispose them yourself 
// when you have many of them
```

Comment: I had the same code before. I thought about that too, but this one is my first request and there are no other requests before it. Still thanks!

Comment: there must be something in your code whether casting or something that's throwing something off that we are missing..

Comment: I made a small example, I would be happy if you could read the edit.

Comment: sure I can look at it and see if i see anything odd or out of place

Comment: I guess you couldn't figure anything out either? Weird indeed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that you posted a console example let me try now.. my bad try adding a slash at the end of this "https://twitter.com/signup/"

Comment: I am going to try one more thing hold on

Comment: Seems like giving up and using another language is the only choice... Thanks for your help, atleast you tried. :)

Comment: Looks like I am getting the same timeout error I wonder if it's a Firewall or port settings issue I can ping 201.38.194.50 and get results but it timesout

Comment: The weird thing is that it hangs only on the twitter link, but for example if you try to open google it works fine.

Comment: maybe Twitter requires some additional type of authentication

Comment: Nope, because it works fine using other proxies or my own ip. Too weird to figure out.

Comment: not your own but something with the twitter.com site itself.. I've never seen this.. this will be a great challenge for someone to figure out

Comment: Well I accepted your answer because you tried to help, seems I'll have to do it another way.